# Is there an equivalent to SQLite R*Tree in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, 3d, spatial

I am in the process of migrating a SQLite database structure to PostgreSQL. This SQLite database uses the R*Tree module with spatial indices for fast 3D bounding box searches.

I have no experience with spatial indexing and PostgreSQL.

I have read the documentation about PostgreSQL GiST indices, which seems to indicate that this enables similar functionality. I have been unable though to find out how to apply this feature to 3D bounding box checks.

I guess that somehow the <@ operator with box and point should do the trick. Can someone elaborate if this intuition is right and provide a small example of how to define a table with spatial 3D data and a query that does a bounding box check?

Here is example data and the query idea that I am looking for:

| id | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

`SELECT id FROM table WHERE x >= 0 AND x <= 2 AND y >= 0 AND y <= 2 AND z >= 0 AND z <= 2`

Comment: Add PostGIS extension and build GiST indexes on geometry columns - that's using r-trees.

Comment: Yes, but PostGIS only has 2-dimensional bounding-box R-trees, as far as I know.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'll have to triple-check, but I think they do support 3d. Otherwise, the index-support of functions like [`ST_3DIntersects()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_3DIntersects.html) would mean the two dimensions are just for initial filtering, after which it has to fully search the third

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe That was exactly it: up to 4d geometries are supported but by default, only the first two will be used to build the tree. To construct it based on all dimensions of the geometry, `gist_geometry_ops_nd` needs to be specified. I've updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html) you set up an up to 4D R-Tree-based index as any other GiST index. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/Cfqrq6gh)

Set up the table with samples:

```sql
create extension postgis;

create table business(
  id int generated by default as identity primary key,
  business_name text,
  x numeric, y numeric, z numeric, t numeric,
  geom geometry(PointZM,4326) generated always as 
      (st_setsrid(st_makepoint(x,y,z,t),4326)) stored);

select setseed(.4);
insert into business (business_name,x,y,z,t)
select 'business_'||n, x, y, z, t
from generate_series(1,1e5,1)a(n),
  lateral(select   n AS n1,
                   180-random()*360 x,
                   90 -random()*180 y, 
                   50 -random()*100 z,
                   50 -random()*100 t)b;
```

Set up the index. Default operator class will only use two dimensions of each geometry to build the r-tree, so you need to specify `gist_geometry_ops_nd` operator class to handle all dimensions of n-dimensional geoms:

```sql
create index geom_idx on business using gist(geom gist_geometry_ops_nd);
```

A test operation, showing index use: selecting 7 points that are closest to a reference point:

```
prepare postgis_based as
select id,business_name,x,y,z,t
      ,(select geom from business where id=42)<<->>geom AS distance 
from business
order by distance
limit 7;

explain analyze execute postgis_based;
execute postgis_based;
```

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=8.59..9.53 rows=7 width=73) (actual time=0.428..1.624 rows=7 loops=1)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Index Scan using business_pkey on business business_1  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
          Index Cond: (id = 42)
  ->  Index Scan using geom_idx on business  (cost=0.28..13468.38 rows=100005 width=73) (actual time=0.427..1.622 rows=7 loops=1)
        Order By: (geom <<->> $0)
Planning Time: 0.351 ms
Execution Time: 1.689 ms
```

| id | business_name | x | y | z | t | distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | business_42 | -91.8261216469166 | 7.7997970642875 | 2.93153014852416 | 13.8754985934873 | 0 |
| 39781 | business_39781 | -91.651074810554 | 10.1567444370512 | 1.08794511732091 | 19.9058199716022 | 6.734198096546056 |
| 10212 | business_10212 | -96.0308356409243 | 6.16780328827525 | 6.99214194619289 | 17.9070448007494 | 7.285942385786669 |
| 78354 | business_78354 | -94.2913320527778 | 12.8802423990292 | 5.95771554931872 | 17.565112372697 | 7.393188423419308 |
| 82772 | business_82772 | -90.3963886636943 | 13.9114309111029 | -2.37759157752899 | 15.9845495479146 | 8.487112236283533 |
| 47097 | business_47097 | -93.041286078567 | 14.2177864450063 | -1.89386518525991 | 11.233109282625 | 8.540133118659915 |
| 94516 | business_94516 | -87.3058458168426 | 1.38796268779309 | 1.78446589911467 | 18.3034143744421 | 9.08111822448362 |

---

If you zero-out `x` and `y` and only populate `z` and `t` while using default index setup, you can [observe slow sequential scans kicking in](https://dbfiddle.uk/WhjIWJuj), indicating only the first two dimensions were used to construct the tree, rendering it unhelpful in that scenario. Once you switch to `gist_geometry_ops_nd`, you start to get [quick index scans](https://dbfiddle.uk/TgACJA2u).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed fiddle which helped me to understand the GiST based solution. It was extremely helpful. Now on to the task of finding out if the client allows to install the PostGIS extension.